# Alfresco - Integration with Ofiice 365?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I need to integrate office 365 with Alfresco community 5.x for editing a document. Is there any way to do that or any addOns available for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Supported Platforms](https://www.alfresco.com/services/subscription/supported-platforms) page to understand what versions of various components are supported for different versions of Alfresco. These apply to both Enterprise and Community.

Office 365 is not listed for any version.